# Get Date Ranges in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that look something like follows

```
Price   | DateTime
--------+-------------
100     | 22/01/2016
210     | 23/01/2016
110     | 24/01/2016
10      | 25/01/2016
20      | 26/01/2016

30      | 13/03/2016
40      | 14/03/2016
50      | 15/03/2016
60      | 16/03/2016
```

Now we can see there are two date ranges in it:

1. 22/01/2016 -> 26/01/2016
2. 13/03/2016 -> 16/032016

How can I query my database to get the above results, i.e the data ranges that I have described? The data can be ordered by date but how to get the range

Comment: Define a date range first. What if there is a gap at sunday, is the date range interrupted or not?

Comment: yes even if its sunday it would be considered as gap, threshold for gap is one day

Comment: What Version of SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your ranges appear to be defined by consecutive dates.  You can assign the groups by subtracting an increasing number -- via `row_number()`.  The rest is aggregation:

```
select min(datetime) as range_start, max(datetime) as range_end
from (select t.*,
             dateadd(day, - row_number() over (order by datetime), datetime) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by grp;
```

Comment: This is very neat but relies on dates being a unique key? If there were two rows for the same date within a range then it would split into two date ranges. Perhaps adding a group by datetime would work - if that's the requirement of course.

Comment: @JohnRC . . . If there are duplicate dates, then use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Comment: That's great - I had not previously seen `dense_rank()` - very useful :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff your answer is correct I am just wondering what if we have to ignore weekends like if the gap is on saturday sunday then the range shouldnt break moreover what if we want to explicitly mention the threshold or gap that breaks the range e.g I want to say that the gap of 2 days shouldnt break my range. Is there any way to do that also.
thanks in advance

Comment: @ahmadsaleem  . . . I would recommend having a calendar table.